Classes, sharedPreferences, providers, and dependencies between them
I have written a class for storing my app's settings. It has functions such as getBackendURL(), setBackendURL(), getLastLoggedOnUser(), setLastLoggedOnUser(), setAccessToken(), getAccessToken(), etc.
My class stores the backendURL and last logged on user and the access token in sharedPreferences. The constructor to my class accepts an instance of sharedPreferences as a parameter.
I have a separate class that handles communication with my backend API. The backendAPIClass needs to get/set the last logged on user and the access token managed by the appSettingsClass.
Every screen in my app will need to use the backend API class. Some screens will need to get/set values in the app settings class.
What's the best way to ensure that every screen in my app can access the backendAPIClass? It seems fishy to create an instance of backendAPIClass on each screen... so would it make sense to code the backendAPIClass as a provider? If so, which flavor of RiverPod provider would be most approrpriate?
If backendAPIClass is a provider, what's the best way to ensure it has access to the appSettingsClass? Do I write the appSettingsClass as a provider, too, so that it can be used both by the backendAPI class and by screens that need to get/set values, or would it be more appropriate to create an instance of appSettingsClass as a member variable in backendAPIClass?

please check this https://github.com/Uuttssaavv/flutter-clean-architecture-riverpod

use Bloc, Provider, Riverpod etc, more here: https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options
